# JMeter BeanShell Listener All Results

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm writing a BeanShell script in JMeter to process the results of the HTTP Requests. I'm able to use the Post-processor to capture these results and process individually however it means adding a Post-processor to every Request.

Is it possible in the BeanShell listener to access all results rather than just the last one which is accessible via the sampleResult, prev variables?

Comment: What do you mean by access all responses ?

Comment: I've 4 HTTP Requests in the plan and I'd like to essentially process the data from each of these to build my own summary report in BeanShell listener

Comment: Resolved this, error on my part. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BeanShell listener fires per request response so by writing the script for it i was able to run it for each http request. Had tried using the Listener before and it didn't work so I tried the post-processor. However it appears it was an issue in my script causing the problem.